# cargo build-bpf failed

Tags: cargo, build-bpf

When I execute the command `cargo build-bpf`, I encounter an error. How can I resolve this issue?

```
error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
   --> src/lib.rs:267:9
    |
267 | /         compile_error!("\
268 | |             target is not supported, for more information see: \
269 | |             https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets\
270 | |         ");
    | |__________^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
   --> src/lib.rs:291:5
    |
291 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
    |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp
```

Cargo.toml

```
...

[dependencies]
solana-program = "=1.16.24"
thiserror = "1.0.48"
spl-token = {version = "4.0.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"]}
spl-associated-token-account = {version = "2.2.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"]}
borsh = "0.10.3"
solana-sdk = "1.16.24"
```

solana-cli 1.16.24
rustup 1.26.0
rustc 1.68.0

Answer (score 3):

I have identified the issue. The solana-sdk is designed for off-chain use only, so it should be removed from the dependencies.